# Update Table rows onClick Events and Remove Previouslly added

Tags: javascript

I want to add new row, and remove previously added row with an `onclick` event.

I write code for it but this code only insert rows not delete previous one.

**js**

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    console.log('hi')
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    element2.name = "txtbox[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element2);


}
```

**html**

```
<input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<table id="dataTable" border="1">
   <tr>

   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `deleteRow()`.. and you might just be able to do it.

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    console.log('hi')
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount) {
        table.deleteRow(-1);
    }

    ...

}
```